# What does "no te pases" mean?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos

I've been learning Spanish for three months and, in order to train my hearing skill, I've recently started to watch a cooking channel on YouTube (in Spanish, of course).

One phrase that I hear very often on this channel is `no te pases`. The girl who runs the channel usually says it while eating the food she has just prepared. Often it is followed by `Mmm... Está muy rico!`.

Now, I already know the meaning of "está rico", but what is the meaning of "no te pases" in this context? The literal translation just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Put one video, to see what you are talking about.

Answer (score 11):

It can be translated as **don't go too far**. It stands for *pasarse de la raya* (the *raya* would be that proverbial line that separates what is okay and sensible from what is not)

> Esa tarta de chocolate está riquísima, pero **no te pases** con ella, que engorda un montón.
>
> **No te pases** con la pimienta, o va a estar demasiado picante.

She could be saying it like `don't get too much`, but I think that in that TV program is used more as a catchy and "trademark" phrase, more than a culinary/health advice about the dish that has just been prepared (specially if is followed by that `Está muy rico`).

The meaning is similar in other contexts: *don't go too far/ don't get too much of something*

> No te pases con Luis

means *Don't be too harsh on Luis*, don't go too far lecturing him, or teasing him.

> No te pases con la bebida, o te vas a emborrachar

would refer to alcohol.

Comment: "Don't cross the line" sounds like an accurate analogy for "No te pases"

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend keeping out of mexican Youtube channels if you're still learning, we have a lot of slang over here and it's hard for someone that's still learning to understand it, words like "güey" for example can be and will be used in multiple context and situations and with different connotations, "güey" can be used as "dude" or as "dumb" or as a major insult depending of how it's said.

In this case, "***no te pases***" if it's coming from a mexican channel it could mean "***this is so good***" but of course talked in mexican slang.

Maybe you can post the video so we can have some context?

Comment: I think this is the correct meaning due to the context where the sentence was taken from. from the example provided: "No te pases, está muy rico" we could translate into English as: "you gotta be kidding me, this is so good/delicious".

Answer (score 0):

This could also mean don't go over board if its used when they are adding ingredients to something you can say "ponle sal a la sopa, pero no te pases" just an example which translates roughly to add salt but don't go overboard.

Comment: Yes, Mac, or even more generally "don't do anything else to it, it's perfect (muy rico) just like it is.